# Unlinked exchanges after Simapro import in Brightway2. Name in the form : <name> {loc} | market for |

Tags: python, brightway

I try to import Simapro CSV into Brightway2.

I have been following [this notebook](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/blob/master/notebooks/IO%20-%20SimaPro%20export%20with%20ecoinvent.ipynb).

I  still have many (200+) unlinked exchange.
When looking at the names, they all follow the same pattern :

```
Cement, Portland {CH}| market for | Cut-off, U
Concrete mixing factory {CH}| construction | Cut-off, U
Diesel, burned in building machine {GLO}| market for | Cut-off, U
Electricity, medium voltage {CH}| market for | Cut-off, U
Gravel, round {CH}| market for gravel, round | Cut-off, U
Heat, district or industrial, natural gas {CH}| market for heat, district or industrial, natural gas | Cut-off, U
...
```

I am considering writing a custom strategy for this, unless this format is familiar to anyone and already implemented somewhere.

Comment: I found [another notebook](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2/blob/master/notebooks/IO%20-%20student%20project%20SimaPro%20export.ipynb) suggesting to use sp.migrate("...")`

The last version of bw2io only contains migrations "simapro-ecoinvent-X.X" until 3.4 though.

I see [this file](https://github.com/brightway-lca/brightway2-io/blob/master/bw2io/data/lci/Simapro%20-%20ecoinvent%203.5%20mapping.gzip) in bw2io but does not seem to be imported in bw.migrations

Comment: I am having the same issue, could you eventually find a way to import?